# Displaying results from pyparsing by striping the quotes and square braces

Tags: python, function, pyparsing

How can I remove the quotes and square braces from the  results of the parsed results so I can store them in a DB to perform analytics

python code :

```
     #!/bin/python
     import pyparsing as pp
     from pyparsing import *
     import string


     # define the grammar for the log file
     integer = Word(nums)
     day = Word(alphas)

     # example log line
     log_display = ("[7]")

     # type of record
     ut_type = "[" + Word(nums) + "]"

     # combine the grammar
     log = ut_type 

     data = log.parseString(log_display)
     print(data)

     display_type = None

     def results(log):
          display_type = ut_type.setResultsName("Type of 
                         Record").setParseAction(removeQuotes)
          print(display_type)
          return display_type

     print("outside the function")
     print(display_type)
```

output when I run the code:

```
     $python test.py 
     ['[', '7', ']']
     outside the function
     None
```

I'd like to have an output :-

```
 Type of Record: 7
```

Comment: Read up on using pyparsing's Suppress class

Answer (score -1):

You can use the replace string function to remove characters from a string.

```
data.replace("[","").replace("]","").replace("\"","")
```

Comment: That gave me an error: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: converted it to a str object and it works but I have some unwanted single quotes i'm trying to get ride of

Comment: '', '7', '' - something like this

Comment: It is better to make the correction in the parser that creates this result, rather than post-process a string representation of the parsed results.